# How to open google map between these points?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have 4 `latlong` points and I want to open the map and make every `latlong` point at on of the 4 corners of the map then set the marker in the center of this map.
these are the 4 points:

> "new_latitude1": 24.790874,
>  "new_latitude2": 24.828583,
>   "new_latitude3": 24.856611,
>  "new_latitude4": 24.837425,
>   "new_longitude1": 46.860488,
>  "new_longitude2": 46.842389,
>   "new_longitude3": 46.86747,
>  "new_longitude4": 46.895313,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

representing the coordinates in pairs would be suggested, for the sake of simplicity.

while you can extend `LatLngBounds` with the coordinates alike this:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
builder.include(new LatLng(24.790874, 46.860488));
builder.include(new LatLng(24.828583, 46.842389));
builder.include(new LatLng(24.856611, 46.86747));
builder.include(new LatLng(24.837425, 46.895313));
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

LatLng center = bounds.getCenter();
```

those `LatLngBounds` can also be used to zoom the map to fit:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));
```